# How to insert an auto-generated id in a Postregsql entity table in another table's ID

Tags: database, postgresql

I have an entity table that I want to auto-generate data from to use as FK in other tables. The generated Id will become the PK in the other tables.

## My Tables

**Users** table with *user_Id* (PK), and other columns such as *firstname*, *lastname*, *email*, *password* etc.

**Entry** table is the Entity table with one *entry_Id* (PK) column.

**Article** table will use the auto-generated *entry_Id* in **Entry** table above as PK with other columns such as *title*, *authorId*, *category*, *created_Date*.

**Photo** table will use the auto-generated *entry_Id* in **Entry** table above as PK with other columns such as *title*, *imageurl*, *authorId* (FK), *created_Date*.

**Comment** table will use *comment_Id* as PK with the auto-generated *entry_Id* in **Entry** table above as FK to form a composite key. Other columns include *user_Id* as FK from **Users** table, *comment*, *created_Date*.

**Flag** table will use *flag_Id* as PK with the auto-generated *entry_Id* in **Entry** table above as FK to form a composite key. Other columns include *user_Id* as FK from **Users** table, *flag_type*.

## What I Want To Do

I want my query to auto-generate the *entry_Id* for **entry** when someone submit a form and automatically used the generated id in other tables such as **Article**, **Photo**, **Comment** and **Flag**.

When I hard coded the values, the **Article** and **Photo** table is accepting one *entry_Id* for multiple rows.

I saw something like this but I am not sure if it's what I want.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');       
INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text'); 
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Is there a script I can use to make the auto-generated id in my entity table re-usable in other tables?

Comment: Put the first insert in a CTE returning id, and use that cte.id in the second insert.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks. Let me look into that.

Comment: I think you are trying to use the Entry table to pull together items such as Article, the author's Photo, and Comments about it together.  If so it fails, at least as describe. For example you say "auto-generated entry_Id in Entry table above as FK." But a FK to what? An Article (or Photo perhaps), but then you don't need a new auto-generated value, but the an old value for the Article (Photo). Actually the Entry table is the source of confusion and complexity. Get rid of it. Then re-look at the relations between your tables. You can re-post the problem in terms of business rues not DB rules

Answer (score 0):

As commented by wildplasser, since version 9.1 Postgres has a nice feature that combines a cte with the `returning` keyword, which allows you to do what you want.

Here is an example based on your pseudo-code:

```
with foo_row as (insert into foo (text) values ('text') returning foo_id)
insert into foo2 (foo_id) select foo_id from foo_row
```

Comment: thanks for the response. In my case, I only have the entry_Id in my entity table so when a user submit a form from the say Article table, I only want to generate the entry_Id in the entity table as primary key and use it as primary key in the Article table. Will I need the line `insert into foo (text) values ('text')` if I don't want to return a text value?

Comment: @JetroOlowole : the identifiers in your question were not consistent. You created this confusion yourself. Now clean it up.

Comment: @JetroOlowole: yes you need the `returning` clause to transmit the `entity_id` generated when inserting in `entity` to the `article` table. So something like: `with entity_row as (insert into foo values() returning entity_id) insert into article(entity_id, title) select entity_id, 'mytitle' from entity_row`

Comment: @GMB thanks for the response. The query is not working because the line `(insert into foo values()` is returning syntax error  for ` ()`. It seems a value need to be provided.